# Getting started with Mathematica packages

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-packages

Can someone offer some advice on how to get started with mathematica packages?

I can save the following in a file named "Foo.m". When I run the input cell in that file, I can see the effects reflected in $ContextPath variable.

```
BeginPackage["Foo`"]

bar::usage = "barfunction";

Begin["`private`"]
bar[w_] := w;
End[];

EndPackage[];
```

However, in my notebook I have the following:

```
#include<foo>
SetDirectory[ToFileName[{$HomeDirectory, "My Documents", "mathematica"}]];
Needs["Foo`"]
$ContextPath
```

But the needs call is failing for some reason, and the $ContextPath remains unchanged.

**Edit**

I believe that I've got a partial solution working now, the cell in my file wasn't marked as an initialization cell - and whilst I can now `<<Foo'`, `Needs["Foo`"]` still isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure the saved file, "Foo.m", is on your `$Path`, which tells Mathematica which directories to look in when trying to load packages, much like the `PATH` environment variable in Unix or Windows.

**EDIT:** `$ContextPath` won't be changed unless there's an actual `BeginPackage` statement (or you manipulate it directly using `Set` or `Block` or something).

**EDIT the second:** One thing to check is what

```
FileNames["Foo.m", $Path]
```

returns. What you're describing does sound a little strange, though.

Comment: Pilly, is it sufficient to simply assume that if the file is in the current working directory (which I believe is set by SetDirectory), and "." is in $Path, that the file should be found?

Answer (score 1):

Either form should work.  When a file is loaded using `Get` (or `<<`) or `Needs`, the directory on the top of the `DirectoryStack[]` is searched first, and then the `$Path` is searched.  (`SetDirectory` does not change `$Path`, so `FileNames["Foo.m", $Path]`won't find `Foo.m`.)  However, `FindFile` by default searches `Directory[]` and `$Path`.  You can test it by doing the following:

```
FindFile["Foo`"]
SetDirectory[<Foo dir>]
FindFile["Foo`"]
```

it should return

```
$Failed
<Foo dir>
<Foo dir>/foo.m
```

If `FindFile` can find `Foo.m` then `Needs` should be able to find it.  In general, I put my packages in `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`, and `Needs` picks them up just fine.